# How to create email address using php , when a user register under my domain name?

Tags: php, email, google-api

I have a domain name say example.com , when a new user created under my domain name I need to create a new email address with its user name 
Eg: username@example.com . The domain is registered under Google business account.

Any body have any Idea , please reply.

Regards

Comment: unrelated to appengine (even if you make the calls from there). look for admin directory api.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use api, check this link : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#json-request

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged as they can disappear over time

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but there is still a link to the official google api.
If the link is no longer valid is that the API has changed ;)
Then it allows you to start a search now..